# please help me. Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, apple-m1

please help me
i found that error while move to another developer device ,
previously i used windows laptop and it was fine, but when i move to mac mini m1 this problem appears
    [Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vSY0.png)

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SI1xq.png)

Answer (score 1):

Got same issue, I solved that by changing "Any iOS SDK" to "Any iOS Simulator SDK" from Xcode in Excluded Architectures section.
[Xcode screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0nkLR.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to Flutter master channel and then check to see if it work or not, then switch back to Flutter stable channel.

Comment: still same error